# how to make reference type for string enum in kotlin and jacoco coverage testable

Tags: kotlin, enums, jacoco

Converted a java class into kotlin in Android app, the jacoco coverage starts to show 0 coverage on a compiler generated function, which is not access able. Other ones seem fine in the report.

[image]

How to make reference type for string enum in kotlin and jacoco coverage testable

java code:

```
public final class Message {

    private Message() { }

    public static class MessageAction {

        public static final String OPEN = "open";
        public static final String VIEW_ALL = "view_all";

        @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
        @StringDef({OPEN, VIEW_ALL})
        public @interface Action { }

        public String mAction;

        public MessageAction(@Action String action) {
            this.mAction = action;
        }

        public String getMessageAction() {
            return this.mAction;
        }
    }
}
```

in kotlin;

```
import androidx.annotation.StringDef

class Message private constructor() {
    class MessageAction(@param:Action var messageAction: String) {
        @kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
        @StringDef(OPEN, VIEW_ALL)
        annotation class Action

        companion object {
            const val OPEN = "open"
            const val VIEW_ALL = "view_all"
        }
    }
}
```

this is sample of how it is used in java code:

```
public static void doSomeThing(@Nullable String message, @Message.MessageAction.Action String action) {
   ...
}
```

and the test:

```
@Test
public void test_messageAction() {
        String testAction = "open";
        Message.MessageAction action = new Message.MessageAction(Message.MessageAction.OPEN);
        assertEquals(testAction, action.getMessageAction());
        }
```

the jacoco test coverage result shows 0 covergate on the function `setMessageAction(@NotNull String var1)` which is in the decompiled java code.
And it is not visible from the code's autocomplete hint.

the kotlin decompiled java code:

```
public final class Message {
    private Message() {
    }

    @Metadata( ...... )
    public static final class MessageAction {
        @NotNull
        private String messageAction;
        @NotNull
        public static final String OPEN = "open";
        @NotNull
        public static final String VIEW_ALL = "view_all";

        public static final Message.MessageAction.Companion Companion = new Message.MessageAction.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker) null);

        @NotNull
        public final String getMessageAction() {
            return this.messageAction;
        }

        public final void setMessageAction(@NotNull String var1) {  //<=== coverage result shows it is not called
            Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(var1, "<set-?>");
            this.messageAction = var1;
        }

        public MessageAction(@NotNull String messageAction) {
            Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(messageAction, "messageAction");
            super();
            this.messageAction = messageAction;
        }

        @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
        @java.lang.annotation.Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
        @Metadata( ...... )
        public @interface Action {
        }

        @Metadata( ...... )
        public static final class Companion {
            private Companion() {
            }

            // $FF: synthetic method
            public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
                this();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding @JvmField resolves it

```
class MessageAction(@param:Action messageAction: String) {
        @kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
        @StringDef(OPEN, VIEW_ALL, CLEAR, TOUCH3D, PLAY, PAUSE, DISMISSED)
        annotation class Action

        @JvmField
        var messageAction: String = messageAction

        companion object {
            const val OPEN = "open"
            const val VIEW_ALL = "view_all"
           
        }
    }
```